# Laravel 4 - How to fix Internal Server Error 500 in all subdomains

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel-4, subdomain

I have a URL [sahabatkartini.com](http://sahabatkartini.com). I build this web with Laravel 4. After i upload it, suddenly all subdomains get **Internal Server Error 500** and sub domain folder appears in the url.

Please take a look at this link:

1. [statistik.sahabatkartini.com](http://statistik.sahabatkartini.com)
2. [blog.sahabatkartini.com](http://blog.sahabatkartini.com)

I suspect the cause is laravel's .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine ON

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

How to fix this? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you check your Apache error.log file to see what the error is when you get 500 in browser?

Comment: Empty , there is no record of errors :(

Comment: Every 500 error has traces in error.log, you're probably not looking at right file.

Answer (score 1):

Add this in to your `global.php`:

```
App::error(function(Exception $exception, $code){
Log::error($exception);
$message = $exception->getMessage();
switch ($code) {
    case 500:
        return Response::json(array('error'=>array(
                'code'      =>  500,
                'message'   =>  $message
            )), 500);
}});
```

Comment: i have tried, but still not work. Still Error 500.:(

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.